# ASP.NET: How to get rid of server side message when there is a validationsummary message?

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have two textbox fields and one 'Save' button. Both textbox have customvalidator to do the validation.
If both textbox pass validation, then click 'Save', a success message shows in a label control(postback from server).
If either textbox fails validation, then click 'Save' button, the error message will display in validationsummary(on client side).
My case is: Firstly end user enters valid value in textbox,then click 'Save' button, a success message shows in label. Then end user changes the value to invalid value, then hit 'Save', Now both success and error message show on the screen. This is because page is not refresh. success message is still on the screen, and at the same time client side validation is failed, so error message show in validationsummary.
So how can I get rid of success message when there is client side error message?
Here is a sample of my code:

```js
function validate1(src, args){
message="The value is out of range";
  var exp=/^[\s\S]{0,8}$/;
  reg=null;
  if(args.Value){
  reg=new RegExp(exp);
    if(!reg.test(args.Value)){
    args.IsValid=false;
      src.errormessage=message;
      return;
    }
    args.IsValid=true;
    return;
  }
}
```

```html
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="false"
    ShowSummary="true" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup" ForColor="Red" />
<asp:Literal ID="ltlMessage" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cmv1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt1" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup"
    Display="None" ClientValidationFunction="validate1"></asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cmv2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt2" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup"
    Display="None" ClientValidationFunction="validate1"></asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup" />
```

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        bool result = DoSomething();
        if (result = true)
        {
            ltlMessage.Text = "Success Message";
        }
        else
        {
            ltlMessage.Text = "Failed Message";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also I can see that `ValidaationSummary` but it shd be `ValidationSummary` . you have `aa` after `d`. kindly remove that too

Comment: Thanks coder for the checking.

Comment: so what is your issue now ?